# Difference between font-size 100% and inherit

Tags: html, font-size, inheritance

Hej

My question is:
 Is setting the style font-size:inherit to an HTML tag equivalent to setting its style to font-size:100%?

As far as I understand, 
 font-size:inherit 
means that the font size in the HTML tag will inherit the font-size from its parent tag, meaning it will have a font-size 100% that of its parent.

Please correct me if I am wrong. I have done several tests to prove that. However, there must be a difference, so could someone point that out to me, please?

Thanks a lot
Jihad Haddad

Comment: Depends on if you're using a relative or absolute font size.

Comment: "However, there must be a difference" — Why?

Comment: I assume there must be a difference, because why else introduce "inherit" as a new value to font-size.

Comment: @JihadHaddad — `inherit` was introduced as a value on *every* CSS property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the specifications, there is no difference in the effects of `font-size: 100%` and `font-size: inherit`. The latter is newer and less widely supported, so there is a practical difference: the latter is ignored by some browsers.